# Can I hang a bathroom cabinet on a single stud and drywall anchors?

Tags: drywall, cabinets, studs, drywall-anchor

I have a 15-20lb wood bathroom cabinet (24 inches wide, few feet tall) and I'll be looking to load it up with heavy bathroom supplies. Problem is there is only one stud available. Do you think one stud + drywall anchors on the other side is enough support? I was thinking it'd be best to cut out the drywall and put a backer board in between the studs?

Comment: How wide is the cabinet?

Comment: 24 inches, the stud is about 9 inches inside on one edge.

Comment: Deleted because of revised previous edit.

Comment: updated, I'm going off memory....the 27 inches I think is the max width I had available.

Comment: Next question: HOW heavy?

Comment: The cabinet itself around 15-20lbs + various full bottles of liquids...maybe 25-35lbs total weight. It's right over a toilet so I really don't want it to fall. There'd be 4 anchor points.

Comment: Last question: does the cabinet have a built in hanging rail?

Comment: yep, it's got two horizontal hanging rails.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While having all four mount points connect to structure (aka: the stud) is ideal, I think in your case, having two mount points in wood and two in a drywall anchor, you're going to be ok.

Consider this question:
[What is the weight capacity of a drywall screw?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/12058/what-is-the-weight-capacity-of-your-typical-2-1-2-drywall-screw-when-driven-1-1)

One drywall screw CAN (not should) hold a lot of weight for its size.  Also a properly installed drywall anchor can typically stand 70~ pounds of pull force (as in pulling out, not down).

With two WOOD (not drywall - wood) screws set into the available stud and 2 (or better, 4) drywall anchors, I think you're not likely to exceed the capacity.  If your cabinet total weight when full is < 100 lbs you're probably not going to have a problem.

Comment: I'll do an extra 2 drywall anchors. So 6 total mount points. I'm gonna throw a 2x4 on the wall so I can rest the cabinet on there while I drill all my pilot holes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this same question about a custom made cabinet I built. I was a little worried but now that I’ve anchored it into the center of the studs with two heavy duty screws it’s basically there for life. Very strong. Super solid.

I very carefully found the exact center of the studs using first a stud finder and then poking nails every few millimeters until I found the exact edges of the stud. And then drilled and screwed. Turned out awesome.

[image][image]